# How to test function, that has two or more input()'s inside?

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, python-unittest

I need to test some python 3 code, and I got stuck testing function with few input()'s.

Example:

```
def two_answers():
    if input("Input 'go' to proceed") != "go":
        return two_answers()
    else:
        while input("Input 'bananas' to proceed") != "bananas":
            print("What?!")
    print("You've just gone bananas!")
```

For functions with one input i use:

```
def test_some_function(self):
    codefile.input = lambda x: 'u'
    codefile.some_function() . . . .
```

And then:

```
def teardown_method(self, method):
    codefile.input = input
```

To revert inputs back.

But here it won't work. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
class SimulatedInput:

    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.args = iter(args) 

    def __call__(self,x):
        try:
            return next(self.args)
        except StopIteration:
            raise Exception("No more input")
```

Then you could use it like you did before:

```
def test_some_function(self):
    codefile.input = SimulatedInput("u","v")
    codefile.some_function() . . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to simulate the user inputs.

You have to use a [**unittest.mock**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) and patch the `input` function.

See the [Quick Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide).

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap the input in to a function.

```
def input_wrap(prompt):
  return input(prompt)
```

Then you can inject it.

```
def two_answers(input_func):
  if input_func('...') != 'go':
    return two_answers(input_func)
  ...
```

Now when you want to test it you can inject a fake or a mock:

```
def test_two_answers(self):
  fake_input = mock.MagicMock()
  fake_input.side_effect = ['go', 'foo', 'bananas']
  two_answers(fake_input) # no assertion for needed since there's no return value
```

Later in the code that executes two_answers you call it like this:

```
two_answers(input_wrap)
```

Answer (score -1):

A minimalistic example with no dependencies. Play with it to extend it as you wish:

```
import sys
import io

def two_answers():
    if input("Input 'go' to proceed") != "go":
        return two_answers()
    else:
        while input("Input 'bananas' to proceed") != "bananas":
            print("What?!")
    print("You've just gone bananas!")

def wrapper():
    lines = ["go", "bananas"]
    def fake_input(*args, **kwargs):
        return lines.pop(0)
    global input
    real_input = input
    input = fake_input
    two_answers()
    input = real_input


wrapper()
```